# how to sum in 2d python array, without Numpyt

Tags: python, arrays

Lets say I have the following array:

```
My_Array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want to sum each of these arrays so the output would be

```
My_Array = [[6],[15],[24]]
```

How can I do this without using Numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python provide an inbuilt function sum() which sums up the numbers in the list.

```
My_Array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print([sum(x) for x in My_Array])
```

If you want to get sum value also as a list then

```
[[sum(x)] for x in My_Array]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be:

```
[[sum(i)] for i in My_Array]
```

I recommend taking a look at Python's naming convention. `My_Array` isn't quite pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use for loop to go over array and sum each array individually and then store it again inside the array.

```
for i in range(len(My_Array)):
    My_Array[i]=[sum(My_Array[i])]
```